# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at pricing.js:122 in magento 2.3.0

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento2.3.0

Hi am getting an uncought referecne error when adding a custom JS in my theme. 
On the console I am getting this error-

```
pricing.js:122 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at pricing.js:122
```

My Pricing.js is an additional Js file, which is causing the error. 
Please suggest how to resolve this error.

My pricing js is attached herewith, [pricing.js](http://confidentialcouture.co.in/ANGEL/pub/static/version1554894752/frontend/Etheme/shopy/en_US/Magento_Theme/js/pricing.js)

> **pricing.js**

```
define('js/theme',['jquery', 'domReady!'], function(jQuery){
    function ajaxCall() {
        this.send = function(data, url, method, success, type) {
          type = type||'json';
          var successRes = function(data) {
              success(data);
          };

          var errorRes = function(e) {
              console.log(e);
              alert("Error found \nError Code: "+e.status+" \nError Message: "+e.statusText);
          };
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                success: successRes,
                error: errorRes,
                dataType: type,
                timeout: 60000
            });

          }

        }

function pricingInfo() {
  //  var rootUrl = "location-api/api.php";
    var call = new ajaxCall();
    this.getManufacturing = function(id) {
        $(".manufacturing option:gt(0)").remove();
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getManufacturing&brandNameId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.manufacturing').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.manufacturing').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Manufacturing Year");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.manufacturing').append(option);
                });
                $(".manufacturing").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                 alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    };

    this.getCondition = function(id) {
        $(".condition option:gt(0)").remove(); 

        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCondition&manufacturingId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.condition').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.condition').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Condition");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.condition').append(option);
                });
                $(".condition").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };
    this.getBrandName = function(id) {
        $(".brandName option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        $(".manufacturing option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getBrandName&producttypeId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.brandName').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.brandName').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Brand Name");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.brandName').append(option);
                });
                $(".brandName").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

    this.getProducttype = function() {
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getProducttype';
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.producttype').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.producttype').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Product Type");
            console.log(data);
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    // console.log(key); console.log(" ");console.log(val+" <br>");
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.producttype').append(option);
                });
                $(".producttype").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

}

$(function() {
var loc = new pricingInfo();
loc.getProducttype();
 $(".producttype").on("change", function(ev) {
        var producttypeId = $(this).val();
        if(producttypeId != ''){
        loc.getBrandName(producttypeId);
        }
        else{
            $(".brandName option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });

 $(".brandName").on("change", function(ev) {
        var brandNameId = $(this).val();

        if(brandNameId != ''){
        loc.getManufacturing(brandNameId);
        }
        else{
            $(".manufacturing option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });

     $(".manufacturing").on("change", function(ev) {
        var manufacturingId = $(this).val();
        if(manufacturingId != ''){
        loc.getCondition(manufacturingId);
        }
        else{
            $(".condition option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });


});

 $('#calculateprice').on('click', function () {
            var manufacturingtext=$('.manufacturing  option:selected').text();
            var conditiontext=$('.condition  option:selected').text();
            var brandNametext=$('.brandName  option:selected').text();
            var producttypetext=$('.producttype  option:selected').text();
            var yourPrice=$(".yourprice").val();
            var email=$("#email").val();
            var mobile=$("#mobile").val();

            var url = calculatetUrl+'?calculate=getManufacturing&brandName=' + brandNametext+'&productType='+producttypetext+'&condition='+ conditiontext +'&manufacturingYr=' +manufacturingtext+'&assetPrice='+yourPrice+'&email='+email+'&mobile='+mobile;
            var call = new ajaxCall();
            var method = "post";
            var data = {};
            var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i

                if(!pattern.test(email))
                {
                  alert('Please provide a valid e-mail address');
                }
                else{
             $('#result').html("Please wait..");
            call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {

            if(data.tp == 1){
                $("#result").html("<span>"+data['result']+" </span>");
              //  $(".manufacturing").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                 alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
                }
   });



    $(document).on('change', '#yourprice', function(){
    $price=$("#yourprice").val();
        if($price>0 || $price!='')
            {
            $("#dynamicview").show();
            $("#calculateprice").show();

            }
        else{
            $("#dynamicview").hide();
            $("#calculateprice").hide();

        }


    });
});
```

Comment: on line 122 change line to this `$(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

Add `require` in your js file

```
require([
    'jquery',
    "jquery/ui"
], function($){
    'use strict';
    //Your Js code here
});
```

And use `jQuery` instead of `$` to avoid conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Use full **`jQuery document ready event`**

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

Try this one:

```
define('js/theme',['jquery', 'domReady!'], function(jQuery){
    function ajaxCall() {
        this.send = function(data, url, method, success, type) {
          type = type||'json';
          var successRes = function(data) {
              success(data);
          };

          var errorRes = function(e) {
              console.log(e);
              alert("Error found \nError Code: "+e.status+" \nError Message: "+e.statusText);
          };
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: method,
                data: data,
                success: successRes,
                error: errorRes,
                dataType: type,
                timeout: 60000
            });

          }

        }

function pricingInfo() {
  //  var rootUrl = "location-api/api.php";
    var call = new ajaxCall();
    this.getManufacturing = function(id) {
        $(".manufacturing option:gt(0)").remove();
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getManufacturing&brandNameId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.manufacturing').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.manufacturing').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Manufacturing Year");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.manufacturing').append(option);
                });
                $(".manufacturing").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                 alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
    };

    this.getCondition = function(id) {
        $(".condition option:gt(0)").remove(); 

        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getCondition&manufacturingId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.condition').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.condition').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Condition");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.condition').append(option);
                });
                $(".condition").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };
    this.getBrandName = function(id) {
        $(".brandName option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        $(".manufacturing option:gt(0)").remove(); 
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getBrandName&producttypeId=' + id;
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.brandName').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.brandName').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Brand Name");
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.brandName').append(option);
                });
                $(".brandName").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

    this.getProducttype = function() {
        var url = rootUrl+'?type=getProducttype';
        var method = "post";
        var data = {};
        $('.producttype').find("option:eq(0)").html("Please wait..");
        call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {
            $('.producttype').find("option:eq(0)").html("Select Product Type");
            console.log(data);
            if(data.tp == 1){
                $.each(data['result'], function(key, val) {
                    var option = $('<option />');
                    // console.log(key); console.log(" ");console.log(val+" <br>");
                    option.attr('value', key).text(val);
                    $('.producttype').append(option);
                });
                $(".producttype").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        }); 
    };

}

$(document).ready(function(){
var loc = new pricingInfo();
loc.getProducttype();
 $(".producttype").on("change", function(ev) {
        var producttypeId = $(this).val();
        if(producttypeId != ''){
        loc.getBrandName(producttypeId);
        }
        else{
            $(".brandName option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });

 $(".brandName").on("change", function(ev) {
        var brandNameId = $(this).val();

        if(brandNameId != ''){
        loc.getManufacturing(brandNameId);
        }
        else{
            $(".manufacturing option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });

     $(".manufacturing").on("change", function(ev) {
        var manufacturingId = $(this).val();
        if(manufacturingId != ''){
        loc.getCondition(manufacturingId);
        }
        else{
            $(".condition option:gt(0)").remove();
        }
    });


});

 $('#calculateprice').on('click', function () {
            var manufacturingtext=$('.manufacturing  option:selected').text();
            var conditiontext=$('.condition  option:selected').text();
            var brandNametext=$('.brandName  option:selected').text();
            var producttypetext=$('.producttype  option:selected').text();
            var yourPrice=$(".yourprice").val();
            var email=$("#email").val();
            var mobile=$("#mobile").val();

            var url = calculatetUrl+'?calculate=getManufacturing&brandName=' + brandNametext+'&productType='+producttypetext+'&condition='+ conditiontext +'&manufacturingYr=' +manufacturingtext+'&assetPrice='+yourPrice+'&email='+email+'&mobile='+mobile;
            var call = new ajaxCall();
            var method = "post";
            var data = {};
            var pattern = /^\b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i

                if(!pattern.test(email))
                {
                  alert('Please provide a valid e-mail address');
                }
                else{
             $('#result').html("Please wait..");
            call.send(data, url, method, function(data) {

            if(data.tp == 1){
                $("#result").html("<span>"+data['result']+" </span>");
              //  $(".manufacturing").prop("disabled",false);
            }
            else{
                 alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
                }
   });



    $(document).on('change', '#yourprice', function(){
    $price=$("#yourprice").val();
        if($price>0 || $price!='')
            {
            $("#dynamicview").show();
            $("#calculateprice").show();

            }
        else{
            $("#dynamicview").hide();
            $("#calculateprice").hide();

        }


    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "domReady!",
  "js/theme"
], 
function($) {
    /* Your code here */
});
```

Try this way.